# Dependent destroy not working, has_many :model, :dependent => :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a Rails 2.3 app with the following setup, why aren't my dependent project_endorsements being destroyed when the project is destroyed?

#### project model

```rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_many :project_endorsements, :dependent => :destroy
  #...
end
```

#### project endorsement model

```
class ProjectEndorsement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

#### My Schema

```rb
create_table "projects", :force => true do |t|
  #...
  t.string   "data_type",                 :limit => 25
  #...
end

create_table "project_endorsements", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "project_id"
  t.integer  "contributor_id"
  t.text     "endorsement"
  t.integer  "sort_order",     :null => false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "project_endorsements", ["project_id"], :name => "index_project_id"
```

#### my failing test

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe ProjectEndorsement do

  let(:project) {  Project.create!( data_type: "Book") }

  let(:contributor) {
    Contributor.new(
      first_name: "Anthony",
      last_name: "Swindle",
      display_name: "Anthony Swindle"
    )
  }

  let(:project_endorsement) {
    ProjectEndorsement.create!(
      project_id: project,
      contributor_id: contributor,
      endorsement: "endorsement",
      sort_order: 1
    )
  }

  context "when a project is deleted" do
    before do
      project.destroy
    end

    it "should remove the project endorsement as a dependency" do
      project_endorsement.should be_blank
    end
  end

end
```

```bsh
$ spec spec/models/project_endorsements_spec.rb 
F

1)
'ProjectEndorsement when a project is deleted should remove the project endorsement as a dependency' FAILED
expected blank? to return true, got false
spec/models/project_endorsements_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@production/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@production/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.171014146 seconds

1 example, 1 failure
```

### Edit: Update - here's a console example showing the project doesn't recognize the has_many association.  This looks pretty relavent...  Also showing the endorsement is not deleted, probably because of the has_many not working above.

#### Console example

```
>> project = Project.create!(data_type: "Book");project.id
=> 11917
>> contributor = Contributor.first;contributor.id
=> 1
>> endorsement = ProjectEndorsement.create!(
?>       project_id: project,
?>       contributor_id: contributor,
?>       endorsement: "endorsement",
?>       sort_order: 1
>>     );endorsement.id
=> 6029
>> ProjectEndorsement.last.id
=> 6029
>> project.project_endorsements
NoMethodError: undefined method `project_endorsements' for #<Project:0x000000050b5040>
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@production/gems/activerecord-2.3.17/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:275:in `method_missing'
  from (irb):10
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
>> project.destroy
=> #<Project id: 11917, data_type: "Book", created_at: "2014-05-08 13:42:22", updated_at: "2014-05-08 13:42:22">
>> ProjectEndorsement.last.id
=> 6029
```

Comment: I am not too deep into rspec, but it seems you are handling the dependency as a has_one, not has_many in your test

Comment: The problem here seems to be the lazyly evaluated let command use let!, since you seem to have deleted the project before project_endorsement has been created.

Comment: I'll try out let! but the endorsement is also not deleted if I destroy the project from the console.

Comment: `let!` won't work on rspec1, but like I said the test is not the problem, it's there just to show the destroy isn't cascading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your

```
ProjectEndorsement.create!(
      project_id: project, # <-- Take a look here
      contributor_id: contributor,
      endorsement: "endorsement",
      sort_order: 1
    )
```

doesn't belongs to `project`.
To be sure try to check in console `endorsement.project`.

You have to use:

```
project_id: project.id,
```

or

```
project: project,
```

as `create!` argument.

Same with `contributor`

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't delete the dependent object until *after* the Project is destroyed, but your test is triggering before the actual destroy command?

I apologize if I'm way off base – as I'm still learning how to do proper testing, but it reads that way to me...

Other possibilities:

`project_endorsements` (plural) should be blank. But I would expect it to return error, not false...

Comment: Good point on the falsey -vs- missing nature, but that's just my uninformed test.  It doesn't explain why the dependency isn't being destroyed.   If I destroy the project in the console it still doesn't destroy the endorsement along with it.